# Project IoT backend for monitoring sensor data

Tags: aws-iot, aws, cloud-computing

I'm newbie to cloud-iot services. I was challenged by my lecturer to build a backend system where it can send sensor data to cloud, store it, and host a website page. Its about monitoring microclimate around a certain area (soil-moisture, temperature, humidity, wind, etc.).

When I think about cloud, I think about AWS, right? But I confused with the services I should use for my project. I dont know what services are the 'best-suit' for my project to store data and display it from AWS IoT-core (my data obtained from some sensor-node like soil-moisture, etc. for microclimate project). That services like dynamodb, lambda, sqs, kinesis, etc idk what more.

Or where can I find tutorial for those (outside aws documentation, because when I searched anything about aws, aws page comes first in search engine)?

Sorry for my bad english, I hope you all can understand what I mean. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out our https://mqttlab.iotsim.io/aws for Getting Started with AWS IoT.